# How to simplify $F(k)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\sum\limits_{d|n}\gcd({d},{\frac{n}{d}})$?

Tags: summation, gcd-and-lcm

I have the following summation:

$$F(k)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^k\sum\limits_{d|n}\gcd\left({d},{\frac{n}{d}}\right)$$

This is nearly impossible to compute (using coding) for large numbers, due to the time it'd take.

It's been suggested that the above summation can be simplified to this:

$$F(k)=\sum_{d=1}^{d^2\leqslant k}\ \sum_{n=1}^{nd\leqslant k}\gcd({d},{n})$$

I've tried testing the simplification, and it doesn't work. For instance, F(10) gives an output of 22 instead of 32.

How do I simplify the first summation?

Stuff here might be relevant, but I'm not sure: [Wikipedia:  Divisor function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function)

EDIT: Algorithm for thefunkyjunky's suggestion:

```
long k = 10;

    for (long d = 1; d*d <= k; d++) {
        for(long n = 1; n*d <= k; n++) {
            if (d*d <= n) result = result.add(BigInteger.valueOf(GCD(d,n)));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I updated my answer to include my original algorithm and an explanation for the transformation of the original summation.

Comment: @thefunkyjunky Yup this works!

Comment: I just updated with a correct implementation of your algorithm.

Comment: Basically, you are asking for the partial sums of [OEIS A$055155$](http://oeis.org/A055155).

Comment: Do you have link to the problem?

Comment: @thefunkyjunky Link to problem: https://projecteuler.net/problem=530
My latest code to solve (which is inefficient only due to my code to check GCD) : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/115026/project-euler-problem-530-gcd-function-is-inefficient

Comment: @Lucian        that's precisely it! I'm trying to make the formula work.

Comment: So have you made your code run fast(after optimizing the gcd function)?

Comment: If this comes fom Project Euler, I guess there is a way to compute this *without* computing lots of `gcd()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that if d is a divisor such that $d<\sqrt{n}$, then $\frac{n}{d} > \sqrt{n}$ and $\frac{n}{d}$ is also a divisor of $n$. So $gcd(d, \frac{n}{d})$ form pairs of gcds, which means that you can compute for divisors only smaller than $\sqrt{n}$ and then multiply the sum by $2$ which is(I think) fast enough.

EDIT:
I forgot to add that you need to make a special case when $n$ is a square, because then you have $d$ that $d^2=n$ and the $gcd(d, d)$ factor must be counted only once, not twice.

EDIT2:
The algorithm I had in mind was:

```
long sum = 0;
for(int n = 1; n <= k; n++) {
    for(int d = 1; d <= sqrt(n); d++) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            if(d * d != n)
                sum += gcd(d, n / d) * 2;
            else
                sum += d; // GCD(d, d) = d
        }
    }

}
```

But I think yours is faster. What you do(if you haven't understood it) in your algorithm is just finding all pairs $(x, y)$ such that $xy \leq k$ which means that their gcd is included in the sum as divisors of some $n = xy$

EDIT3:
The algorithm that you firstly tried to implement(the rewritten sum) has a mistake. It can be written as(The following is a combination of my and your solution):

```
int sum = 0;                                                                                            
for(int x = 1; x * x <= k; x++) {                                                                        
     for(int y = x; x * y <= k; y++) {                                                                    

         if(x != y) sum += 2 * gcd(x, y);                                                                
         else sum += x;                                                                                  

     }                                                                                                   
 }
```

Please comment to tell me whether it passes(I'm also interested)!

Comment: That's what the suggested simplification in my post tried to do, I think. But the result it gives is incorrect. :/ It could be that you're suggesting something different. Could you express what you suggested in summation form? :)

Comment: just the same as the summation you gave, but with the additional condition $d \leq \sqrt{n}$. To be precise - do you want an algorithm for doing this sum?

Comment: Hang on, let me try and implement that! I don't want to unnecessarily trouble you. :)

Comment: I've edited my post to include an algorithm. I don't know if this is what you had in mind, but it doesn't give the correct output.

Comment: Ah, I wrote the algorithm before seeing your edit (EDIT1) about the special case! Now this works perfectly! Time to see if it can handle the computation time.

Comment: Hang on, this code isn't quite the summation suggested + an extra condition right? Because in this code, we're still doing factorisation, which is what is causing it to take a long time to compute (I think). However, your suggestion is definitely faster than my initial summation so many thanks!

Comment: @TheveshTheva What is the maximal K? The complexity of my algorithm is O(K*sqrt(K)) which should pass if K<=50000(if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: It does pass even up to k = 10^6. Unfortunately, the value of k we're looking to solve for is 10^15. :O

Comment: This algorithm works! However, the implementation time is far too long. It's taken more than 3 mins to compute 10^9, which would make it impossible to compute larger. It computes 10^6 instantly. :/

Answer (score 2):

I have found another way to calculate this, although I am not really answering the question of how to rearrange the original sum.

I started by considering for myself the possible pairs and the $gcd$s:

```
n= 1:  (1,1)                        1                 f( 1)=1   F( 1)= 1
n= 2:  (1,2)  (2,1)                 1  1              f( 2)=2   F( 2)= 3 
n= 3:  (1,3)  (3,1)                 1  1              f( 3)=2   F( 3)= 5
n= 4:  (1,4)  (2,2)  (4,1)          1  2  1           f( 4)=4   F( 4)= 9
n= 5:  (1,5)  (5,1)                 1  1              f( 5)=2   F( 5)=11
n= 6:  (1,6)  (2,3)  (3,2)  (6,1)   1  1  1  1        f( 6)=4   F( 6)=15
n= 7:  (1,7)  (7,1)                 1  2  1           f( 7)=2   F( 7)=17
n= 8:  (1,8)  (2,4)  (4,2)  (8,1)   1  2  2 1         f( 8)=6   F( 8)=23
n= 9:  (1,3)  (3,3)  (9,1)          1  3  1           f( 9)=5   F( 9)=28
n=10: (1,10)  (2,5)  (5,2) (10,1)   1  1  1  1        f(10)=4   F(10)=32
```

I didn't find it obvious what was going on here, so I laid out the same results like this:

[image]

I noticed that the table can be viewed as a set of inverted "V"s.

The entries for $(1,n)$ and $(n,1)$ make one such V: with all the $gcd$ equal to 1.

The entries for $(2,\frac n2)$ and $(\frac n2,2)$ make another V (marked in green): but the entries start with 2 and then alternate 1, 2, 1, 2, ...

It is important to note also that the $i$th V begins at $n=i^2$ with a single value $gcd = i$, then continues on with $2(i-1)$ values of $gcd=1$ and then 2 values of $gcd=i$, with this pattern being repeated.

By my method we have $F(n)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{i={\sqrt n}}V(i,n)$

where $V(i,n)$ is the sum of the values in the $i$th V and is found by this algorithm:

Find positive integers $p$ and $q$ so that $n=pi^2+qi+r$.

Then $V(i,n)=i + 2(p-1)(2i-1)+2q$

I think this might be better because there is no need to calculate any $gcd$.

Comment: I'm currently out, but this is absolute genius. I can't wait to try it when I get back.

Comment: This isn't quite right. For i = 4, it begins with a single value gcd = 4, then it has 2 values of gcd = 1, 2 values of gcd = 2, 2 values of gcd = 1, then back to 2 values of 4. Hmmm, trying to find a general pattern now.

Comment: In fact, to my dismay, the V pattern is non recurring. 

`For the 1st V: 1......`
`For the 2nd V: 2,1,2,1....`
`For the 3rd V: 3,1,1,3,1,1..`
`For the 4th V: 4,1,2,1,4,1,2,1....`
Similiar chaos on others. 
`For the 8th V: 8,1,2,1,4,1,2,1....`

Comment: Sorry about that - I will havea look at it further.